# Message Queue VS Thread Pool

Tags: multithreading, threadpool, message-queue

What the difference between message queues and thread pools?

Comment: @S.Lott: "Otter" and "Peace" would be more like it. Otters and Horses are both 4-legged animals after all...

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: Queue and Pool are both collections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real question would be whether there's any similarity between the two. A message queue is a data structure for holding messages from the time they're sent until the time the receiver retrieves and acts on them.

A thread pool is a pool of threads that do some sort of processing. A thread pool will normally have some sort of thread-safe queue attached to allow you to queue up jobs to be done. This would more often be called something like a "task queue" than a message queue, though it will normally contain some sort of messages that describe the tasks that need to be done.

Comment: I wonder does the message queue enforce the sender and receiver must came from different process or thread.

Comment: @peterwkc: every message queue I've seen allows a thread to post a message back to itself.

Comment: It does make sense for me at least to post a message back to itself. Please clarify with example.

Comment: @peterwkc: one example would be a window for something like a test that has a timer running so when the window first shows, it has (say) 60 seconds remaining for you to fill in the blanks. When it's first displayed, it sets a timer to have a message posted back to itself once a second to update the timer, and after 60 seconds, tell you that you've run out of time.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: Good example. Thanks for your example.

Answer (score 7):

[Message Queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue) is used for (asynchronous) inter-process communication while a [Thread Pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern) is used to run multiple tasks on a set of threads. I can't think of a reasonable way to compare them... they're fundamentally different from each-other in so many ways.

Answer (score 0):

`message queue` usually used in distributed system, `thread pool` often used in individual machine. btw `thread pool` use blocking queue internally. if you use `message queue`, you will cost more time to maintain it. Don't over-designed.
Of course, `message queue` hava more complex features, and good at decoupling.
(ps: u can look at the question：[Why are message queues used insted of mulithreading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828064/why-are-message-queues-used-insted-of-mulithreading/4828143) )